# How do I change tab icon?

Tags: html, image, icons

I am trying to change the tab icon of my website. Here's the image now: [image: Tab Icon]

I want to change it to this:

[image: My custom icon]

Here's my code to change the tab icon:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/appicon.ico">`

Comment: The tag looks okay, in case the path to your favicon is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the  element to your index.html file right below the  element. Your code should now be like this:

```
...
<title> Sammy’s First Website </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="Favicon_Image_Location"/>
...
```

Make sure to replace Favicon_Image_Location with the relative file path of your favicon image.

Comment: I have fixed it. Turns out I just had to add ../ because the icon wasn't in the directory of my website.